# Citation to Recursive Feature Elimination with CV Algorithm

Tags: scikit-learn, rfe

Does anyone know the citation to the article from where RFECV is based upon? I have looked into the documentation and here and found nothing about it.

Looking here I found the following reference http://rdcu.be/xFbx but there is no explicit connection between this reference and the implemented code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From the code [docstring](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f1ab2d060fd49c94a6e3386291a684ec7/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py#L368-L373) or the numpydoc [rendered](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) version:

> Guyon, I., Weston, J., Barnhill, S., & Vapnik, V., “Gene selection for cancer classification using support vector machines”, Mach. Learn., 46(1-3), 389–422, 2002.